# Opening a project in VS Code from the command line creates multiple empty instance

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I've opened several projects on vscode and it creates several empty instances in the application switching (cmd+tab)

This is recent and it seems like a mix between two expected behaviours:

Behavior 1:

- multiple projects = multiple app icons in the app switch context
- you switch between them by using `cmd+tab`

Behavior 2:

- multiple projects = one app icon in the app switch context
- you switch between projects by using cmd+`

Buggy behavior:

- multiple projects = multiple app icons in the app switch context
- you switch between projects by using cmd+`
- all of the vscode instances do nothing, except for one that brings vscode up
- the actual vscode icon is indistinguishable from the other 'ghost' instances.

How can I get rid of all those extra icon instances?

I'm on a macosx 11.6.1

VSCode is:
Version: 1.63.2
Commit: 899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3

I'm launching projects with `code`

`which code` returns `/usr/local/bin/code`

`cat /usr/local/bin/code` outputs

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
# Licensed under the MIT License. See License.txt in the project root for license information.

function realpath() { python -c "import os,sys; print(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[1]))" "$0"; }
CONTENTS="$(dirname "$(dirname "$(dirname "$(dirname "$(realpath "$0")")")")")"
ELECTRON="$CONTENTS/MacOS/Electron"
CLI="$CONTENTS/Resources/app/out/cli.js"
ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1 "$ELECTRON" "$CLI" --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node "$@"
exit $?
```

[image: vscode]

Comment: It may help if you include your OS and what version of vscode you use, as well as an actual question. It seems your post only contains statements instead of a question.

Comment: thank you, just added the extra details

Comment: are you opening vscode from a terminal by running 'code' ?

Comment: yes I am! feels like you know something hahah