# How to modify an app installation on a Mac?

Tags: macos, installation

How can I modify (meaning go back to the setup wizard and change the settings of a specific app, or is there a better way to do that) an app so I could put the directory in a different PATH or change any of the app's settings?

BTW

I am asking this question to solve another question on Super User.

NOTE: I am a Windows user with only a few experiences with Mac.

Comment: If you're not a Mac user, you probably shouldn't try to answer Mac questions.

Comment: Macs don't use "setup wizards". They rarely use installers at all. Most apps are simply dragged from a disk image [.dmg] file to either /Applications or ~/Applications, depending on whether they're intended for all users or just one. As @Spiff says, if you don't have this basic knowledge about Macs already, it's probably not an area you should be thinking about answering. Link us to what it is you think this will help so we can see what you're trying to do.

Comment: It is this question: https://superuser.com/questions/1696745/vs-code-creates-multiple-empty-instances

Comment: Ah hahaha vscode. An Electron-based app from Microsoft. Microsoft's apps for macOS almost never follow the rules, and Electron apps aren't native enough to follow the rules. Yeah, even I, as a very experienced Mac user, wouldn't touch that question without first reproducing the problem on a Mac and proving out my proposed solution on a Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no common/standard way to do what you're looking for.

Mac apps rarely use installers any more. Being prompted for install-time options is rare.

It sounds like you're specifically interested in Vscode. Microsoft distributes Vscode for macOS as simply the app itself, zipped. Once you unzip it you drag and drop it wherever you want it to live on your filesystem, and that's it. It doesn't have install-time options or a real setup assistant. It has some "getting started" screens that walk you through customizing minor preferences like syntax coloring schemes and stuff, but nothing that would relate to that other question about the multiple running instances.

Comment: In the question about vs code opening multiple running instances, I wanted to solve that problem because that has happened to me before on a Windows 10 machine in Google Chrome every time I clicked chrome on my taskbar it opened a new window instead of opening a tab in the same window. I solved the problem by going to add or remove programs and modifying chrome settings and then reinstalling Chrome but I didn't know how to modify app settings on a Mac.